# How to make my javascript calculator calculate decimal numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently my simple javascript calculator is capable of calculating whole numbers. However it is incapable of doing so with decimal numbers like 3,4 or 9,2 etc...
getal1 & getal2 stand for number1 & number2. The functions are plus, minus, multiply, and divide respectively.

```js
function plus()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseInt(getal1) +  parseInt(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
  
function min()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseInt(getal1) - parseInt(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
  
function keer()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseInt(getal1) * parseInt(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
  
function delen()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 

 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseInt(getal1) / parseInt(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Oefening calculator
  </title>
  <script src="Javascript.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
 </head>
  <body>
  
   <div id="calculator">
   
   <!-- Invoervelden getal1 en getal2 -->
    <form id="point1">
     <label for="getal1">
      Geef 1e getal :
     </label>
     <input type="number" name="getal1" id="getal1">
    <br />
     <label for="getal2">
      Geef 2e getal :
     </label>
     <input type="number" name="getal2" id="getal2">
    </form>
    
   <!-- De som knoppen -->
   <div id="knoppen">
    <button onClick="plus()">
     +
    </button>
    <button onClick="min()">
     -
    </button>
    <button onClick="keer()">
     x
    </button>
    <button onClick="delen()">
     /
    </button>
   </div>
    <br />
    
   <!-- Het resultaat tekstblok -->
    <form id="point3">
     <label for="resultaat">
      Resultaat
     </label>
     <input type="number" name="resultaat" id="resultaat">
    </form>
    
   </div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you tried replacing all parseInt by parseFloat?

Comment: You only need to use *parseInt* or *parseFloat* for addition, for multiplication, division and subtraction, string values can be used without issue (provided they are valid numbers of course).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `parseInt` to `parseFloat`. `parseInt` is integer numbers, not decimals, and it ignores the decimals when users enter decimal numbers.

Example for your plus function:

```
function plus() {
    var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
    var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value;
    document.getElementById('resultaat').value = parseFloat(getal1) + parseFloat(getal2);
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code which can divide decimat numbers too. Just change parseInt with parseFloat. You can round off your answer like this

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

```js
function plus()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseFloat(getal1) +       parseFloat(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
  
function min()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseFloat(getal1) -       parseFloat(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
  
function keer()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseFloat(getal1) *       parseFloat(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
  
function delen()
{
 var getal1 = document.getElementById('getal1').value;
 var getal2 = document.getElementById('getal2').value; 
 document.getElementById('resultaat').value=parseFloat(getal1) /       parseFloat(getal2);
 document.form1.submit();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Oefening calculator
  </title>
  <script src="Javascript.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
 </head>
  <body>
  
   <div id="calculator">
   
   <!-- Invoervelden getal1 en getal2 -->
    <form id="point1">
     <label for="getal1">
      Geef 1e getal :
     </label>
     <input type="number" name="getal1" id="getal1">
    <br />
     <label for="getal2">
      Geef 2e getal :
     </label>
     <input type="number" name="getal2" id="getal2">
    </form>
    
   <!-- De som knoppen -->
   <div id="knoppen">
    <button onClick="plus()">
     +
    </button>
    <button onClick="min()">
     -
    </button>
    <button onClick="keer()">
     x
    </button>
    <button onClick="delen()">
     /
    </button>
   </div>
    <br />
    
   <!-- Het resultaat tekstblok -->
    <form id="point3">
     <label for="resultaat">
      Resultaat
     </label>
     <input type="number" name="resultaat" id="resultaat">
    </form>
    
   </div>
   
  </body>
</html>
```